# ConstIterator from Iterator definition

Tags: c++, class, iterator

In a tree template class, a ConstIterator is being defined from an Iterator in the following way:

```
template <typename k_T, typename v_T>
class Tree<k_T, v_T>::ConstIterator : public Tree<k_T, v_T>::Iterator {
  using parent = Tree<k_T, v_T>::Iterator;

 public:
  using parent::Iterator;
  const std::pair<k_T, v_T>& operator*() const { return parent::operator*(); }
};
```

but it's not clear to me what the `using parent::Iterator` is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It inherits the constructors of `parent`.

> If the using-declaration refers to a constructor of a direct base of the class being defined (e.g. using Base::Base;), constructors of that base class are inherited [...]
>   The inherited constructors are equivalent to user-defined constructors with an empty body and with a member initializer list consisting of a single nested-name-specifier, which forwards all of its arguments to the base class constructor.

See *Inheriting constructors*:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration